# How to infer the max current output of this function generator from its datasheet/specs?

Tags: function-generator, specifications

I need to figure out the max current a function generator can output from its signal waveform output. [Here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/499058.pdf) is its datasheet. But there is no such parameter here.

The output voltage can swing from -10V to +10V.
But I cannot find any detail about the maximum load or current. Can we say it can source current for a load down to 50 Ohm? Does that mean it can source max 10V/50Ohm = 200mA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function generator has a 50\$\Omega\$ output impedance and is protected from short circuits. To me, this **implies** that the maximum current is limited by the open circuit voltage (up to 20V) and the output impedance. Ohm's Law says the maximum output current should be 400mA when the output is shorted or 200mA into an external 50\$\Omega\$ load.

Having said that, it makes me uncomfortable that there is no specification for the output voltage range with a 50\$\Omega\$ load. It may be that the sheet you linked is an abbreviated version of the full specifications.

Comment: Longer manual here https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/13f8/0900766b813f8f55.pdf but this doesnt provide either.